# presentViewConroller *without* transparency

Tags: ios, swift

I prepare for changing (ios7+ Swift code) view controller like this:

```
tmpNewViewC!.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyle.CoverVertical;
```

And later show it like this

```
tmpOldViewC.presentviewController(tmpNewViewC!, animated: true, completion: nil);
```

The problem is that the the animaion effect overlays the new view transparent on the old making it look really messy for a while (both visible at the same time)

I just want both the views to be fully non-transparent while the animaion effect runs. The things I have tried have failed.

Comment: To my knowledge no. However, It is true that i use .png files with transparency in them as background in he views. However, it is not just the background that shines through - it is everything on both the old and new view. i jus raher have the effect to not use any transparency at all. (i.e. have one view slide into the other, but not as a transparent overlay)

Comment: 1) All the non-transparent elements also becomes transparent. Are you arguing that non-transparent things also become transparent in  because there is a .png image with transparency in the view behind it all? 2) And even so, it does not change the question at hand - i.e. how to turn transparency off for the animation 3) How can I assume noone else sees the problem? I try not to make assumptions

Comment: I am not using segues so not applicable... (If you really want to know, the project was ported from another development solution and language where transition logic was already done and hence kept for the time being) -- Yes, I am aware that segue offers a transition effect not even possible when using presentViewController with any of the modalTransitionStyle options (except "custom" I guess)

Comment: @matt i guess you are claiming DeyaEldeen answer is wrong when he states it is not possible? As well as the SOs that can not mimic the default transition effect when using presenViewController. You then ask to create a demo project (after claiming the usage of a transparent .png makes the entire view behave with transparency - which may be true even hough it sounds odd to me considering there are controls that otherwise do not behave with any transparency) using a different way than what I am currently using. And then I point that out, you immedialy move to close question.

Comment: I'm not saying he's wrong. On the contrary: it is certainly true that you could use a custom transition and put some sort of backing view behind your view as it rises up. I'm saying that _you_ are making this happen. If you don't want it to happen, you will need to not to do what you are doing that makes it happen.You're hitting yourself in the face and complaining that your face is being hit.

Comment: @matt Okay roger that. I will investigate that with the background image. Must be that which is the cause. Maybe I can apply some code to it before the present  - might even be to swich off the background image. I will try experiment with that or accept I will need to do a custom transition. If you want to provide it as an answer, I will upvote it.

Answer (score 1):

you need to create custom transition as the default ones don't have all the options you need or want...
a simple google search leads to this [link](http://zappdesigntemplates.com/custom-uiviewcontroller-transition-ios-swift/)
so in short, you have to forge your own custom transition.

Comment: if he answer is that what I need can not be done / is a known problem - and I need to create a custom transition handling everything - I guess it is an answer that will help me not waste time barking up the wrong tree... Still hoping for a fix though that can eliminate the overlay transparency when using the ConverVertical animation

Comment: I will probably end accepting this as he answer, but I will the question up for a while in case someone knows of a "hack" solution (e.g. applying some kind of code towards the views before that removes the transparency in the transition effect)

Comment: when you create this transition, can you post it as a github gist?
good luck.